# How do I use [camera takePhoto] and edit using UIImagePicker - UIImagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, photos

I'm going to feel dumb but I've searched everywhere and have not found an answer. I've been able to pull up the "edit" view using the default camera's controls. However I threw an overlay on it and I have a UIButton hooked up to IBAction take photo which looks like [UIImagePickerController takePicture].

However, it totally skips the editing part even though I set allows editing to YES. Is there another command to call it? Right now, it just goes straight to didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.

```
    camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    camera.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    camera.showsCameraControls = NO;
    camera.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    camera.toolbarHidden = YES;
    camera.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    camera.allowsEditing = YES;
    camera.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
    [self presentViewController:camera animated:YES completion:nil];
```

then in IBAction

```
    [camera takePicture];
```

Comment: can you put the code of takePhoto..?

Comment: are you using this line of code  UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; in delegate method..?

Comment: Yes, I am, but I want the edited photo (the cropped square one). However, the screen that lets me crop it does not appear after I take a picture with my Overlay UIButton. It appears however, if I just select a photo from the photo library, just not when I take a picture.

Comment: i think your cropped photo not saving correctly...put some code then i can check..

Comment: @MuditBajpai That's the problem, the UIPickerController is not even taking me to the crop photo (edit) screen. It doesn't let me edit it even though I set edit to YES.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [UIImagePickerController does not show edit screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577830/uiimagepickercontroller-does-not-show-edit-screen)

According to takePicture: method in Apple documentation:

> Use this method in conjunction with a custom overlay view to initiate the programmatic capture of a still image. This supports taking more than one picture without leaving the interface, **but requires that you hide the default image picker controls.**
>
> Calling this method while an image is being captured has no effect. **You must wait until the associated delegate object receives an imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: message before you can capture another picture.**

It seems that this approach (custom overlay) it is configured in order to be managed by yourself. Even if "allowsEditing = YES" the taken picture will be directly sent to imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:.

Based on that if we want to edit the taken picture using our custom user interface we should create an according custom edit screen for that purpose.

Comment: The crop rect stucks in the center, how do i crop the top square of my image instead

Comment: @Happiehappie You may want to create a different question entry for that, I'm sure you will find someone that can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

The problem of not showing the Edit screen is associated with the **camera.showCameraControls = NO;** the presence or absence of overlay has nothing to do with it (as the current accepted answer states)

**Possible workaround:**
on your IBAction [camera takePicture] set them again to YES. They will be shown only for a fraction of a second and that will allow the edit screen to appear. Then you will have a problem when hitting "Retake", in that case you have to capture that action via delegate and hide them again there.