# UIImagePickerController does not show edit screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm playing around with a cameraOverLayView and encountered a weird behavior.   Before presenting the UIImagePickerController, I set allowsEditing to YES.   After the capture screen comes up, I tap on a button that triggers takePicture().    Instead of presenting the editing screen, the delegate method didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo() gets called right away.   Can anyone help me figure out what I could be doing wrong?   I pasted some of my code below...

Thanks!

```
    - (BOOL)shouldStartCameraController {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) {
        return NO;
    }

    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    float overlayOffset = 0;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
            overlayOffset = 195;
        } else {
            overlayOffset = 103;
        }
    } else {
        /*Do iPad stuff here.*/
    }


    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]
        && [[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:
             UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {

        cameraUI.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) {
            cameraUI.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
        } else if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]) {
            cameraUI.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
        }

    } else {
        return NO;
    }


    UIView *cameraOverlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cameraUI.view.frame.size.width, cameraUI.view.frame.size.height)];
    UIImageView *cameraOverlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone5_camera_overlay.png"]];
    cameraOverlayImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cameraUI.view.frame.size.width, cameraUI.view.frame.size.height);
    [cameraOverlayView addSubview:cameraOverlayImageView];


    UILabel *cameraLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.height-overlayOffset, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50.0f)];
    [cameraLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [cameraLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [cameraLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cameraLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.300f]];
    [cameraLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake( 0.0f, -1.0f)];
    [cameraLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f]];
    [cameraOverlayView addSubview:cameraLabel];

    UIButton *cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, cameraOverlayView.frame.size.height-60, 50, 50)];
    [cancelButton setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f]];
    [cameraOverlayView addSubview:cancelButton];


    UIButton *snapButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [snapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(takePictureButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [snapButton setFrame:CGRectMake(110, cameraOverlayView.frame.size.height-60, 100, 50)];
    [snapButton setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f]];
    [cameraOverlayView addSubview:snapButton];
    cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;
    cameraUI.delegate = self;
    self.imagePickerController = cameraUI;

    [self presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated:YES];

    return YES;
}


- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    [self shouldPresentPhotoCaptureController];
}

#pragma mark - UIBarButton Selectors

- (void)takePictureButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"takePictureButtonPressed...");
    // TODO: take picture!
    [self.imagePickerController takePicture];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible dublicate: [How do I use [camera takePhoto] and edit using UIImagePicker - UIImagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184224/how-do-i-use-camera-takephoto-and-edit-using-uiimagepicker-uiimagepickercont)

According to takePicture: method in Apple documentation:

> Use this method in conjunction with a custom overlay view to initiate the programmatic capture of a still image. This supports taking more than one picture without leaving the interface, **but requires that you hide the default image picker controls.**
>
> Calling this method while an image is being captured has no effect. **You must wait until the associated delegate object receives an imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: message before you can capture another picture.**

It seems that this approach (custom overlay) it is configured in order to be managed by yourself. Even if "allowsEditing = YES" the taken picture will be directly sent to imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:.

Based on that if we want to edit the taken picture using our custom user interface we should create an according custom edit screen for that purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate is redirecting to another possible duplicate.